# finding mistake in $\alpha^2(b)=b$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $X=\langle a,b|a^{2^m}=b^2=1,[a,b]=a^2\rangle , m\ge3$ and $\alpha \in Aut(X)$ (automorphis group of X)
If 
\begin{cases}
\alpha(a)=a^{2^{m-2}+1}b\\
\alpha(b)=a^{2^{m-1}}b
\end{cases}
and $a^2,b^2\in Z(X)$
I want to get $\alpha^2(b)=b$ but when I do the math I get
$α^2 (b)=α(a^{2^{m-1}}b)=α(a^{2^{m-1}} )α(b)=(a^{2^{m-1} }b)^{2^{m-2}+1} a^{2^{m-1}}b=a^{2^{2m-3}+2^{m-1} } a^{2^{m-1}} b^{2^{m-2}+1}b=(a^{2^m} )^{2^{m-2}} a^{2^m } b^{2^{m-2}}b^2=b^{2^{m-2}}$
where I do it wrong?
I edited it and I am not sure if $b^{2^{m-2}}=b$

Comment: What definition of $[a,b]$ are you using?

Comment: $[a,b]=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$

Comment: I think you missed the $b$ from the $\alpha(a) = a^{2^{m-2}+1}b$ substitution.

Comment: I think you have some mistakes. The third relation is equivalent to $b^{-1}ab=a^3$, so $a=b^{-2}ab^2=a^9$, and hence $a$ has order at most $8$. But it looks as though you are intending $a$ to have order $2^m$. Also, for $m=3$, it is not true that $a^2 \in Z(X)$, and your $\alpha$ is not an automorphism because $a$ has order $8$ but $a^3b$ has order $4$.

Comment: this is part of a counterexample so I not it's not true

Comment: You can't expect to get consistent results if you are working under false assumptions!